# C# Regex expression to match numbers, hyphens, colons, spaces and commas

Tags: c#, regex

I haven't used regex before so if anyone could lend a hand that would be awesome.
I have text similar to this:

2016-09-16 14:25:28,756

stored in a string.  I want to create a regex to see if what was entered contains numbers, hyphens, colons, spaces and commas.  What would be the regular expression for this?  Also, would there be a way to compare the string to a specific order of a regex?  For example, if someone enters:

2012-10-18 15:29:37,886

this would be correct because the form is

####(hyphen)##(hyphen)## (space) ##(colon)##(colon)##(comma)###

Comment: does order matter? are you looking for the exact examples you're giving? or are you just checking if the string contains all of that criteria? What regex have you tried?

Comment: Order is the most important, but if there is a way to check for the exact order that I posted then that would be great.  I tried this regex @"[0-9\-:,]" but that's obviously not correct.

Comment: Are you actually searching for a date and time? Use `DateTime.ParseExact`, not a Regex.

Comment: Just in case you don't actually need regular expressions and you just want to parse a date time of a specific value: I would use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` giving the exact format you expect which appears to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff`. E.g., `DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-09-16 14:25:28,756", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);`

Comment: Is `9016-29-26 44:65:68,756` a valid text? If *not*, have a look at `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There may be easier/more intuitive solutions than regex, as @DourHighArch mentioned.

Comment: The problem is when I go to highlight text in a textbox in wpf, I want to place the highlighted text into another textbox, but only if the text has the form above.  If there is a letter in the highlighted text, I want to throw an error so that the user can select another piece of text that will contain the form that was specified above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an exact match to the text you have, I would use:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}[,]\d{3}");
        Match match = regex.Match("2012-10-18 15:29:37,886");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value is a match.");
        }
    }
}
```

A great resource for validating and testing regular expressions is:
http://regexr.com/

Comment: Technically, your solution matchs the question, but I doubt if input `9016-29-26 44:65:68,756` should be accepted

Comment: If the op wanted to check for valid dates, I would say yes. It doesn't sound like that is case though.

Comment: This matches strings with superfluous characters at the beginning and end which also may not be desirable. E.g., it will return success on the strings `asdf2012-10-18 15:29:37,886asdf`, `2222012-10-18 15:29:37,886234234`